# "if and only if" Proof

Tags: logic, proof-writing, terminology, solution-verification

Let C and D are inductions, assumptions or known results. I want to show that '$A$ holds if and only if $B$ holds'. Is the following proof structure true?

"Indeed, it suffices to see that $C$ to prove the if direction. Conversely, assume that $B$ holds. Since we have $D$, it follows that $A$ holds.

Are there other suggestions to improve the proof?

Comment: Where did $C$ and $D$ come from? What is the context? You have to prove two implications $A\implies B\land B\implies A$. For $\iff$ to hold, $\tau(A)=\tau(B)$. It's either $\tau(A)=\top\land\tau(B)=\top$ or $\tau(A)=\bot\land\tau(B)=\bot$. I'm sorry, but you didn't prove anything.

Comment: C and D are inductions, assumptions or known results

Comment: How can you write a proof not mentioning it before? Besides, your sentences are incomplete, e.g.: "It suffices that $C$ to prove..." $C$ what?

Comment: I don't understand your English. Your post lacks clarity.

Comment: It might help if you illustrated the problem with an example.

Comment: In fact, I focus here on the English and the structure of the proof without using logic symbols. For example, is the " if direction" more suitable to mean the implication $A\implies B$?.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, if you want prove that $A \iff B $, you need to show that $A\implies B$ and B$\implies A$

Comment: That has already been said in the comment section. 

Comment: Sorry I missed that-didn't see it.